# How to implement CLLocationManager.requestLocation() on iOS 8 or older?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cllocationmanager

If you have read the new iOS 9 docs, you may have noticed a new method which causes the location manager to power up radios for a brief amount of time, get a fix on your location and once desired accuracy (or timeout) is reached, turn it all back off, handing the pinpointed location over to the delegate.

The method is called `CLLocationManager.requestLocation()` and is available in the iOS 9 SDK. Alas, I'm currently working on an app targeting iOS 8 and would still very much like to make use of this method. I also wouldn't like to reimplement it all myself.

So here's my question: Is there any open-source library for iOS implementing this kind of one-time location retrieval?

Comment: you may like to use "INTULocationManager"

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Arslan Asim* pointed out, a good solution would be to use [INTULocationManager](https://github.com/intuit/LocationManager).

From the docs:

```
manager.requestLocationWithDesiredAccuracy(.Block, timeout: 10.0) {
    (currentLocation, achievedAccuracy, status) in
    // Examine status to see if the request timed out.
    // If not, currentLocation stores the found location.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform two steps first

1) `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

2) `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Then

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    // locationManager.locationServicesEnabled
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    let Device = UIDevice.currentDevice()

    let iosVersion = NSString(string: Device.systemVersion).doubleValue

    let iOS8 = iosVersion >= 8

    if iOS8{

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
else{
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

This will Help.Thanksyou

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I was looking for. After starting the location updates, I need to wait some time to get the accuracy to an acceptable level or cancel in case the timeout fires.